# What is wrong with this syntax? Batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, syntax

I'm trying to run this command in the windows cmd and I get a syntax error.

```
REG QUERY "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /d /t REG_SZ
```

this command outputs the current current wallpaper directory, and I wanna set a string with it (the directory) and then copy the wallpaper to my desktop.

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`REG QUERY "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /d /t REG_SZ`) DO (
SET var=%%F
)
copy "%var%" "%userprofile%\Desktop\wallpaper.bmp"
```

I could do it manually but in my case it must be done automatically.

Comment: Please explain what you want to accomplish. Right now all we can say is that "Yes, that command will give you a syntax error", so clearly that is not the right command. In order to help you figure out what the *right* command is we would have to know what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors:

- Don't use `/T` or `/D` on a query
- with tokens=* you get the value and type in front of data
- copying to the fixed extension `.bmp`can be wrong (irfanview reclaimed wrong type, here it required jpg)

---

```
@Echo off
FOR /F "tokens=2*" %%A IN (
    'REG QUERY "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper'
) DO SET "var=%%B"
copy "%var%" "%userprofile%\Desktop\wallpaper.bmp"
```

**EDIT** The assignment to var isn't necessary, you can copy directly with  :

```
) Do copy "%%B" "%userprofile%\Desktop\wallpaper.bmp"
```

Answer (score 0):

This script copy the actual set Wallpaper from the location, given by the REG Value Wallpaper under the **HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop** Key, onto your desktop.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "tokens=2* delims= " %%A IN ('REG QUERY "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper') DO COPY %%B "%userprofile%\Desktop\"Wallpaper.jpg
```

- delims is a TAB followed by a space, you can set it to what ever you want default is the TAB followed by a space.
- tokens=x,y,m-n    -   specifies which tokens from each line are to be passed to the for body for each iteration.
  This will cause additional variable names to be allocated.
  The m-n form is a range, specifying the mth through the nth tokens.
  If the last character in the tokens= string is an asterisk, then an additional variable is allocated and receives the remaining text on the line after the last token parsed.

### Simple words TL;DR:

- **delims** describes the "spaces"  or stuff that separetes stuff from each
- **tokens** is which of the output blocks do u want (* means all after too)
- **%%A** (or %A) is the first cached token, %%B is the second

kind regards MEv